# Azure SQL Data Sync: invalid characters in table names

Tags: sql-server, azure, synchronization

I have been running SQL Data sync for the past half year without any major problems, until i recently discovered some errors in my sync that i then went to solve. After that, i tried to refresh the tables that was configured for synchronization. When i pressed save, i got an error saying that "Update failed":

Failed to perform data sync operation: Tables (table name) contains character ' ' which is not supported by Data Sync.

The database i am trying to sync, is part of a MS Navision database - all tables are therefore named: [Company Name$Value Entry]

I was able to add 40 tables with this naming convention, when the sync was setup initially 6 months ago, but now i can't add any tables named the same way.

I tried to create a similar table, but without the whitespaces and $ character ([CompanyNameValueEntry]), and that went through without any hassle - but i obviously can't rename the database tables of the Navision database - so is this a new restriction on the SQL Data Sync feature? I can't seem to find any information about this.

If that's the case, are there any alternatives to sync a database between Azure and on-prem SQL, other than the standard Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent Client application?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Dennis Mortensgaard, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could think about [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

Copy the data between on-premise SQL Server and Azure SQL database.

Ref these tutorials:

- [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
  Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
- [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)

Create a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) to schedule sync the data.

This could be an another option, but we need pay for the data transferring.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using the SQL Compare tool from DBForge - which does a good job, and let us control the sync much more in detail than we could with the default Azure SQL sync .